# Looping through an array of links and toggling their classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I loop through an array of about 7 links. 6 of the links have the same class named "current-link", while 1 has a different class named "previous-link"

So here's the issue, on a click event on one of the links, I want to:

1. Check if any link has the class "previous-link" and then toggle it to "current-link"
2. change the class of the clicked link to "previous-link".

Note: Only one link should have the class "previous-link"

```
<div class="sport-types stUp"> 
    <span>
      <a href="" class="previous-link">Football</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Hockey</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Tennis</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Basketball</a> |   
      <a href="" class="current-link">Handball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Volleyball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Baseball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Am. Football</a> |  
      <a href="" class="current-link">Rugby Union</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">More sports >></a> 
    </span>
</div>


const sportTypeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.stUp > span > a');


sportTypeLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       const markedLink = e.currentTarget.classList.contains('previous-link') ? 'current-link' : 'previous-link';   

    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this function.

```js
const sportTypeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.stUp > span > a');

sportTypeLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        document.querySelector('.previous-link').className = "current-link"
        e.currentTarget.className = "previous-link";
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="sport-types stUp"> 
    <span>
      <a href="" class="previous-link">Football</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Hockey</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Tennis</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Basketball</a> |   
      <a href="" class="current-link">Handball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Volleyball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Baseball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Am. Football</a> |  
      <a href="" class="current-link">Rugby Union</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">More sports >></a> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you keep updating your answer accordingly to my updates?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class `previous-link` only if the clicked one doesn't contain it already.

```js
const sportTypeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.stUp > span > a');

sportTypeLinks.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // run function only if target does not have 'previous-link' class
        if(link.className != 'previous-link'){
          // change the previous class
          document.querySelector('.previous-link').className = 'current-link';
          // add previous class to clicked element
          link.className = 'previous-link';
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.previous-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport-types stUp"> 
    <span>
      <a href="" class="previous-link">Football</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Hockey</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Tennis</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Basketball</a> |   
      <a href="" class="current-link">Handball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Volleyball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Baseball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Am. Football</a> |  
      <a href="" class="current-link">Rugby Union</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">More sports >></a> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it as follow:

```js
const sportTypeLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.stUp > span > a');

for(let i = 0; i < sportTypeLinks.length; i++){
  let link = sportTypeLinks[i];
  link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let changeIfNeeded = link.className != 'previous-link' ? changeClass(link) : null;
  });
}

function changeClass(el){
  document.querySelector('.previous-link').className = 'current-link';
  el.className = 'previous-link';
}
```

```css
.previous-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sport-types stUp"> 
    <span>
      <a href="" class="previous-link">Football</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Hockey</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Tennis</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Basketball</a> |   
      <a href="" class="current-link">Handball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Volleyball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Baseball</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">Am. Football</a> |  
      <a href="" class="current-link">Rugby Union</a> | 
      <a href="" class="current-link">More sports >></a> 
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a longer method